# Applying tr() function

Tags: qt4

Hi i'm not able to apply `tr()` to `strings`, which are passing to a `function`. 
Please can you help?

```
MainWin::SetMenuBarButton (PdCount,"File", LEFT);
```

How to apply `tr()` function to string `File` ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where that call is. If it is outside any `QObject`, you need to prefix it by `QObject`:

```
MainWin::SetMenuBarButton (PdCount,QObject::tr("File"), LEFT);
```

**Edit** to use it in a function that expect a `const char*`:

```
MainWin::SetMenuBarButton (PdCount,QObject::tr("File").toAscii(), LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

its just a function that takes the string. a simple google search could help.

`tr("FILE")`

Comment: tr() function returns a QString as "File" is passed to function SetMenuBarButton as 'const char*'. So it gives me error of cannot convert from QString to Char*

Comment: @Prashant: This is why you post your error messages when you ask your question.

Comment: There are so many QString methods to convert it to `const char*` such as `QString::constData()`, `QString::toAscii()`, `QString::toLatin1()`, `QString::toLocal8Bit()` choose the variant you need. But I'll Quote @Bill How the hell can one know that you are having problem in converting the QString to const char*

Comment: @Neel: Prashant's comment was `it gives me error of cannot convert from QString to Char*`.  This is exactly the kind of information that belongs in the question, instead of only as a response after someone has answered what you actually asked.

Comment: Oh! Sorry I overlooked that Comment. I was checking the question for new edits :(